# Python: reference to other instances of class objects

Tags: python, class

Idea is that class contains several instances and when one of instances is called for some method, it checks for all other existing instances of the same class for some value. Or, perhaps, it will be easier to formulate in code:

```
class foo:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value

    def getvalues(self):
        self.magichappenshere = '?'

Joe = foo(5)
Bob = foo(4)
Jon = foo(3)

Jon.getvalues()

#expected output:
#12
```

How to refer to other instances without explicitly calling them? I was thinking of giving additional name attribute in `__init__` which corresponds to instance name as in `Joe = foo("Joe", 5)` and accumulates in some sort of outside list. But that didn't seem like a very good solution. What would be THE way to do this?

Comment: If an instance is garbage collected, should the value of getvalues decrease or remain the same?  I.e., is getvalues supposed to be the sum of the values of all the things ever created (in which case, a static counter is appropriate), or of all currently existing things?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can 'register' your instances with your class, in a class attribute:

```
class foo:
    _instances = []

    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
        foo._instances.append(self)

    def getvalues(self):
        return sum(instance.value for instance in foo._instances)
```

Note that this'll keep instances around forever! You'd have to use [weak references](https://docs.python.org/2/library/weakref.html) to avoid that:

```
from weakref import WeakSet

class foo:
    _instances = WeakSet()

    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
        foo._instances.add(self)

    def getvalues(self):
        return sum(instance.value for instance in foo._instances)
```

The `WeakSet()` keeps track of objects without keeping them alive; if any other references to an instance drop to 0, the instance is cleared from memory and the `foo._instances` weak set will simply stop listing it.

Demo:

```
>>> from weakref import WeakSet
>>> class foo:
...     _instances = WeakSet()
...     def __init__(self, value):
...         self.value = value
...         foo._instances.add(self)
...     def getvalues(self):
...         return sum(instance.value for instance in foo._instances)
... 
>>> Joe = foo(5)
>>> Bob = foo(4)
>>> Jon = foo(3)
>>> Jon.getvalues()
12
>>> del Joe
>>> Jon.getvalues()
7
```

Comment: After some basic testing on different applications this seems to be working every time. Now off I go to implement this in my project. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use a [class attribute](http://www.toptal.com/python/python-class-attributes-an-overly-thorough-guide) to keep track of the sum of the values

```
class foo:
    value_sum = 0
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
        foo.value_sum += value

    def getvalues(self):
        return  foo.value_sum
```

In python you don't need a getter so I would just access the class attribute directly:

```
class foo:
    value_sum = 0 
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
        foo.value_sum += value


Joe = foo(5)
Bob = foo(4)
Jon = foo(3)

print foo.value_sum
```

Comment: The problem is not in adding numbers together. I don't think this would work in a iterative function where, say, instance has some coordinates and it checks the coordinates of other instances before taking some action on every iteration.

Comment: @A.Val., it is just a simple example of a class attribute, it is shared among instances, the link I provided has  detailed explanation and use cases, how you manipulate it  it is completely dependent on what you want to achieve

Comment: You are also not handling *instance deletion* here.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, where exactly in the question does it mention anything about deleting instances, the question is way too broad to go through every possible scenario but the common element that will certainly be needed is using a class attribute

Comment: I agree the question is on the broad side; there is no One True Way here at least.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, I think definitely after seeing the OP's comment on your answer that the class attribute was the missing piece of the puzzle.